# Determinant of a rectangular matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I don't know how to read $|F|_{pq}$ in this paper ([Eisenfeld 1976 - Block diagonalization and eigenvalues](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379576900264)). Is it a determinant of rectangular matrix? Or is it some other metrics? Note that $F$ is a matrix with p rows and q columns.

[image]

Comment: That's not a determinant. It is the metric referred to in the first paragraph you quote, presumably defined earlier in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

By $|F|_{pq}$ Eisenfeld denotes a norm ! For details see page $210$.

Comment: Thanks Fred, but what does it mean "norm !"? I've read the page 210 hundred times but I don't understand how $| |$ is defined.